# Suggestion for creating templates for my characters animations with Meta-rigs?

Tags: bones, unity, rigify

hi everyone I am working on a lowpoly proyect.

I would starting to rigging and skinng all my 3D characters . I ve finished all them all.

I ve divided  3 class of models for PC game.

main characters ( 4 males and 2 woman , 2K maps x 4 texture)
NPC  (level 1 to 5  ,  2k maps x 3 textures).
bosses  (level 1 to 5 , 2 k maps x 4 texture) this could be change according performance, batches, drawcalling ,etc...

I am thinking of a sytem , bone-system to save my time and interchange bones  ,acording to classes ( all melee's NPC has the same weapon and the same animation all the time) at least for this first pass of testing...(then I will bring more weapons or animations). I need to mark my workflow with the main programmer too.

I am not animator , I am  3D generalist and programming too , but I am  focused on rigging process  this last 6 month , keep learn,  you know ,so for and so it.

first thing I need to establish a good template of bones ( type or "meta-rig" and define the animation acording to the classes objects )

I discard "pitchpoy"  for now , at least in this first pass  , just for cinematics or whatever (even blendrig is fun for that) in theory...

I am not too much time for the deadline , to enjoy the manual rigging process , I need a testing  and define things. So I am thinking on  Rigify (a kind of meta-rigs which incorporated interesting things in 2.79 ++ of blender, of course).

My goal is PC  , and Unity 2018.1  , free vertion (or upgrade to pro , in case we need it).

is it possible to trick a template  for my  character's classes with rigify addon ?  saving my metarig as a template (I do not want to start from 0 everytime I start the rigging... I do not need pitchpoy for this pass ).

should I use  Rigify in unity 2017/2018  ? honestly... I prefer manual , but Manual is a little consuming time , but I do not deal too much with mechanism , legagy or generic , in unity inspector...also the "root" bone...that 's an extra thing to take a gaze....

I am not big fun of "automatic-weitgh" most of the time I use empty vertex group and assingned them to a specific group or bone.
So that can be take in mind ??

Honestly ,  I would like to focus in few animations , such as Idle state, running , jumping, attack , death , taunt pose , enter to something .

the possibility to transfer bone  to a another  objects or append them to an object , is good option , remember, blender to unity is the key ? I am thinking the best way to save time and start the animation process. generally speaking, all the things you can make in blender has blender's purpose output...in my case,  I use blender most of the time ,but my goal is a game in Unity , So I would like to hear a solid and argue answer. thanks .

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this question falls in this category, but just in case: Please avoid open ended questions and keep them as short as possible. (https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

I am not a Blender expert either, but one way I found to reuse armatures is the append function in Blender:

1. File => Append (shift+f1)
2. Select your blender file
3. Open Object folder
4. Select the metarig you want to re-use
5. Parent your object to the armature
6. Refine the weights with whatever method(s) you are comfortable with